# Escape HQL keyword

Tags: nhibernate, escaping, keyword

I use NHibernate 1 and have a HQL query

```
SELECT mo
FROM MyObject mo
WHERE mo.Group = blabla
```

MyObject has a property called "Group". This is a HQL keyword, so I get an error

```
Unexpected syntax near keyword "Group"
```

Is there a way to escape the keyword? I read that this is not the case, but perhaps that´s not right? Using [] does not work. I also read you can use "backticks" in the mapping file but what is the right way to do it? If I have

```
<property name="Group" />
```

in the mapping file?

Comment: using backticks is the proper way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the right method is using backticks in the following way:

```
<property name="Group" column="`Group`" />
```